# "Could not find a compiler version matching 0.8.2" error from Truffle on macOS when not using sudo

Tags: solidity, truffle

If I don't use sudo, `truffle compile` gives me an error: [`truffle compile` output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoOX6.png).

With sudo there is no error: [`sudo truffle compile` output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t5m2.png).

Why does that happen?

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it was very light on details and all the crucial info is in screenshots. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I improved it a little but I think it would be more helpful to others (and easier to find with a search engine) if you could replace the screenshots with text. I.e. just copy Truffle output from the console and paste it into the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by wrong permissions on some of Truffle's files/dirs in your system. They're probably owned by root and Truffle cannot write there. Simply removing the configuration should fix the issue:

```bash
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/truffle-nodejs
```

Alternatively you might use `chown` to change ownership of those files but if you never modified the config manually just removing it is simpler and Truffle will recreate it for you and also redownload the compiler binaries when needed.

This was recently reported by many users in [Can't compile solc version "^0.8.9" #4431](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/4431) but does not really seem to be a bug in Truffle itself. Not sure why it was so widespread - is some popular tutorial telling people to run Truffle with `sudo` or something? If you do, Truffle will create some files as root and won't be able to overwrite them or create new ones unless you keep running it with `sudo`.